# Client Server with IPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, client-server

I have a bit of a design question if anyone at there cares to offer some advice (or point me in the right direction).

I am writing an IPad app that will be gathering data from a server and then will be using that data for some time (read: it would be nice to be able to store the data locally even when the app is not running). Anyone know of the best way to accomplish a feat like this.

Essentially, order of events would preferbly go something likes this:

1. User launches app.
2. IPad requests data from server.
3. Server supplies data.
4. User interacts with app etc.
5. User closes app.
6. At a later time, user launches app again.
7. App checks data, sees it is still up to date, reads in previous data from disk.
8. User interacts with data etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application is launching for the first time you should get all the data and store in to a local database.

When the user open the application after some other time just write make a webservice call that check for the last updated time, if it matches your time then leave it,else update the database.